# Query that returns only records that do not match on a specific field

Tags: ms-access

I am *not* an Access person, just trying to write what I think is a simple query to do the following:

I have two tables in my database, imported from two separate SharePoint lists. So I do not have control over the format of the data. I will call one table the MASTER table and one table the SUBSET table. The MASTER table contains a complete list of all possible values that could appear in the SUBSET table.

Both tables have a field that contains a URL, but these fields are different data types. In the MASTER table, the URL field's data type is Text. In the SUBSET table, the URL field is of data type Hyperlink.

In addition, it is possible that some values in the SUBSET URL field do not exactly match the matching value in the MASTER URL field. So, if the MASTER URL is `http://abc.example.com` the SUBSET URL may contain additional information, like `http://abc.example.com/home.apsx` for example.

What I need is a query that returns all records from the MASTER table that do not have a matching URL record in the SUBSET table.

The desired output is a list of all RequestAccessEmail values that do not have a matching URL in the SUBSET table.

[image: Query attempt]

For each RequestAccessEmail value, include it in query results only if the associated URL value has no match in the SP Permissions Cleanup Tracking URL field.

```
Internal Site Owners
ID
Url
RequestAccessEmail
Attachments
1478
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/itfrance
First.last1@example.com
0
1673
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/PricingSupport
First.last2@example.com
0
1652
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/POProjectMgmt
First.last3@example.com
0
1655
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/POSTeam
First.last4@example.com
0
1741
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/rsa6x
First.last5@example.com
0
1218
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/EMEAProjectSupport
First.last6@example.com
0
65
http://projectsites.example.com/sites/folsom
First.last7@example.com
0
1595
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/NBPCA
First.last8@example.com
0
1664
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/prepaiddev
First.last9@example.com
0
1634
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/patchmgmt
First.last10@example.com
0
1961
http://os.example.com/sites/manager
First.last11@example.com
0
 
ID
Name
URL
8
CFPB AuditsDOMAIN_e0117427.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/itfrance/home.aspx
9
St. Pete Legal DepartmentDOMAIN_e0117427.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/PricingSupport
10
Retail Contracts (7)DOMAIN_e0117427.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/POPProjectMgmt
11
China HR SharesDOMAIN_lc23494.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/ChinaHRShares
12
Client LoyaltyDOMAIN_e1033221.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/clientloyalty
13
eZoom! Human Resources R1.1DOMAIN_e1007952.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/ezoom-hr
14
IntercompanyDOMAIN_e0119924.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/intercoproject
15
NDMS Mentoring ProgramDOMAIN_e1033265.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/NDMSMentoring
16
Human ResourcesDOMAIN_e0015957.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/HR
17
International Human ResourcesDOMAIN_e1019184.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/GlobalHR
18
Site Title FSG Resource Central DOMAIN_e0102084.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/ResourceCentral/SitePages/Home.aspx
19
TAGDOMAIN_e1022064.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/TAG/SitePages/Home.aspx
20
WP Employee_Community EngagementDOMAIN_e1034583.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/WPEmpEngmt
21
Legal (6) - Root Site (reviewed all subsites except CID- DOJ- ACI 2011)DOMAIN_e0117427.xml
http://legal.example.com
22
Consulting Services Client PortalDOMAIN_e1035127.xml
http://clientportal.example.com/sites/consulting/default.aspx
23
YMCA Fitness ChallengeDOMAIN_e1035127.xml
http://projectsites.example.com/sites/Morgano/default.aspx
24
OSNETDOMAIN_e0000185.xml
http://os.example.com/Pages/default.aspx?sdupgwelredir=1
25
USVS_ Government SolutionsDOMAIN_e0113967.xml
http://infoport.example.com
26
Global ServicesDOMAIN_e0113967.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/GlobalSvcs/default.aspx
27
Check Training _ Quality ServicesDOMAIN_e0113967.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/QATrain
29
AutoSuites ArchiveDOMAIN_e0067145.xml
http://sp-archives.example.com/sites/autosuite/SitePages/Home.aspx
30
VCI Client SiteDOMAIN_e0067145.xml
http://clientportal.example.com/sites/VCI/SitePages/Home.aspx
31
VCI Internal SiteDOMAIN_e0067145.xml
http://teamsites.example.com/sites/VCI-IUO/SitePages/Home.aspx
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? An example of the output you would like to achieve would also be helpful.

Comment: You can use the query design window to get started. You can drag and drop fields to create a link, you can edit the link type with right-click, or you can edit from the ribbon. When you have an example, post it with notes on the problems.

Comment: You can use the Find Unmatched Query Wizard under the Query Wizard option for this task.

Comment: I tried the Find Unmatched Query Wizard, but it returns all records from the master table. I am assuming that this is because of the data type mismatch between the two URL fields.

Comment: Edited question to include more detail. The Criteria formula is ([Internal Site Owners].Url<>[SP Permissions Cleanup Tracking].URL)

I get an error when running the query: "Cannot join on Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object."

Comment: The query should return a list of email addresses, the source for which is the RequestAccessEmail field in Internal Site Owners. Each record in Internal Site Owners contains a RequestAccessEmail field and a URL. The SP Permissions Cleanup Tracking table contains a URL that may or may not exactly match the URL from the Internal Site Owners table. The results of the query should be a list of all email addresses in the RequestAccessEmail field such that the URL on the record does not have a matching URL in the SP Permissions Cleanup Tracking URL field.

Comment: Please don't post pictures, there are of almost no use, because thate data has to be typed for testing. Even badly formatted cut and paste of data is much more use.

Comment: Sorry. Is my latest edit more useful?

Comment: No :) Just a cut and paste from each of the tables is what is needed, however, I am not sure that your data is what it seems to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if something like this works for you:

```
SELECT Distinct m.URL
FROM [Internal Site Owners] m, [SP Permissions Cleanup Tracking] s
WHERE s.URL Not Like "*" & m.URL & "*"
```

You will need to paste the SQL in SQL View of the query design window.

The query asks for rows where the master URL is not like the subset URL, so `http://abc.example.com` will match `http://abc.example.com/home.apsx`, but not `http://home.abc.example.com`. The format of a hyperlink type is usually `display text#http://example.com#`, so `http://example.com` in the master will match.

**Edit re data and comments**

[image: query and tables]

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.RequestedAccessEmail, m.URL
FROM [Internal Site Owners] AS m, [SP Permissions Cleanup Tracking] AS s
WHERE s.URL Not Like "*" & [m].[URL] & "*"
```

**New version from sample data**:

```
SELECT [Internal Site Owners].RequestAccessEmail FROM [Internal Site Owners] 
WHERE ID NOT IN (
     SELECT [Internal Site Owners].ID
     FROM [Internal Site Owners], [SP Permissions Cleanup Tracking]
     WHERE [SP Permissions Cleanup Tracking].URL 
        Like "*" & [Internal Site Owners].[url] & "*")
```

Comment: The SQL view makes a lot more sense to me. This is close to what I need (except that I need distinct RequestAccessEmail)  but it seems to be returning exactly the same results as:
    `SELECT DistinctAccessEmail
    FROM [Internal Site Owners]`
So it does not appear that the URL comparison is doing anything.

Comment: What is your sql? The above is a comparison of URLs as mentioned in your post, where is DistinctAccessEmail coming from and what is it supposed to match?

Comment: I have: `SELECT Distinct m.RequestAccessEmail FROM [Internal Site Owners] m, [SP Permissions Cleanup Tracking] s WHERE s.Url Not Like "*" & m.URL & "*";`

The RequestAccessEmail is from [Internal Site Owners]. I am trying to generate a list of email addresses that do not have a matching URL in the SUBSET table.

Comment: You will need to post some sample data. string comparison of this type is not exact.

Comment: You could always check the length of the 2 join fields and if there are less than or equal to 255 characters, change to text data type, then a join will be permitted. However, the hyperlink would have to be cleaned up. I do not use the hyperlink data type, it is far more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: As you can see, using the data you suggest, I am getting the result you expect. Perhaps the data is not quite the same as posted?

Comment: It's entirely possible. I'll need some time to genericize the actual data, and will post soon.

Comment: Hmmm. That just causes Access to display the first 50 or so records, with many more columns than just the email addresses, and then it goes into (Not Responding) mode. It doesn't looks like there are a ton of records getting generated, but it's impossible to tell for sure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26977/discussion-between-remou-and-chad-dybdahl)